# OpenACC: Complex loop carried dependence of '*(*(b))' prevents parallelization

Tags: cuda, openacc, pgi-accelerator

I am using OpenACC with dynamic array allocation. Here is how I allocate:

```
float **a;
float **b;
float **c;
float **seq;
a=(float**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float*));
b=(float**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float*));
c=(float**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float*));
seq=(float**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float*));
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        a[i]=(float*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float));
        b[i]=(float*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float));
        c[i]=(float*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float));
        seq[i]=(float*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(float));
}
```

and here is how I am paralleling the matrix add:

```
#pragma acc kernels copyin(a[0:SIZE][0:SIZE],b[0:SIZE][0:SIZE]) copy(c[0:SIZE][0:SIZE])
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                        c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
                }
        }
```

When I compile this code with `pgcc` it detect dependency on `float**` pointers over loop iterations and generates all scalar kernel (1 block 1 thread-per-block) which performs poorly as expected:

```
 40, Complex loop carried dependence of '*(*(b))' prevents parallelization
     Complex loop carried dependence of '*(*(a))' prevents parallelization
     Complex loop carried dependence of '*(*(c))' prevents parallelization
     Accelerator scalar kernel generated
     CC 1.0 : 11 registers; 40 shared, 4 constant, 0 local memory bytes
     CC 2.0 : 22 registers; 0 shared, 56 constant, 0 local memory bytes
```

The loop is obviously parallel and I think this can be detected by compiler too. I am curious how to explain it to `pgcc`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be unrelated to your question, but AFAIK you should avoid having float** structures. Float** are not contiguous in memory, and I don't know how the copyin would work in this case. You can simply allocate your 2D matrix as a 1D array, and a[i][j] == a[i + SIZE * j]. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're definitely right! Sure it help! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The key is to use `independent` clause:

```
    #pragma acc data copyin(a[0:SIZE][0:SIZE],b[0:SIZE][0:SIZE]) copy(c[0:SIZE][0:SIZE])
    {
             # pragma acc region 
             {
                    #pragma acc loop independent vector(16)
                    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                            #pragma acc loop independent vector(16)
                            for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                                   c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
                            }
                    }
             }
    }
```

Comment: You should also be able to use the [restrict](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v4n1a1b.htm) keyword on the declarations of a, b, c (probably only on c is needed) to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks! I tested it as you suggests and the loop is parallelized as expected. It looks they work the same way in this small sample.

Comment: what does `vector(16)` signify?

Comment: @anup `vector(16)` hints the compiler to use 16-wide vectors for executing the loop. For instance, if the compiler is compiling OpenACC for CUDA-capable devices, the compiler may use 16 threads across the thread block dimension.